# Units of nav_msgs/Odometry

Tags: navigation, odometry, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I would appreciate if you can tell me what are the units used for nav_msgs/Odometry :

- twist : linear and angular twists

is it in meter and radians per seconds ? or meters and radians per timestamp ?

Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288813/units-of-nav_msgs/odometry/) by [lounis](https://answers.ros.org/users/33728/lounis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see [REP-103: Standard Units of Measure and Coordinate Conventions](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-16**:
And a bit pedantic perhaps, but this has been asked and answered quite a few times already.

Suggestion: use google for any searches, and add `site:answers.ros.org` to the query.